# IPC между C++ и C# используя MMF

Tags: c#, c++, ipc

Как передать строку из C++ std::string в приложение на C# используя Memory Mapped File?

Comment: Данные передать несложно, но вам нужен ещё какой-то протокол синхронизации между двумя программами.

Answer (score 0):

std::string str; 
str хранит символы во внутреннем массиве, к которому вы легко можете добраться через &str[0] и размер вы легко найдете среди методов класса.

Этот массив можно записать в файл, который можно прочитать в программе на с#.

Размер массива и его адрес может меняться, поэтому для ipc придется создать файл, отобразить его в память, а потом передать аллокатор классу std::string, чтоб он располагал массив в нужном адресном пространстве. Это гемор, а результат не отличается от записи в файл, именованный канал или сокет.

Если прям надо писать в виртуальную память другого процесса, то:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

/*функция печати ошибки*/
DWORD show_err(LPCTSTR msg) {
    LPTSTR str_err;
    DWORD no = GetLastError();
    if(FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, no, MAKELANGID(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), &str_err, 0, NULL)) {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("%s: %d\n%s\n"), msg, no, str_err);
        LocalFree(str_err);
    } else
        _tprintf(_TEXT("%s:\nномер ошибки %d\n"), msg, no);

    return no;
}

/*получение идентификатора нужного процесса*/
DWORD getProcessID(TCHAR * pName) {
    DWORD ret = 0;

    /*получим указатель на слепок всех процессов в ядре OS*/
    HANDLE snapHandle;
    if((snapHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось получить список всех процессов"));
        return ret;
    }

    /*получаем первый процесс из слепка*/
    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry = {sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)}; //требуется сообщить о типе структуре через её размер в первом поле 
    Process32First(snapHandle, &processEntry);
    do {
        /*остановимся, когда найдем нужный процесс по его имени*/
        if(_tcscmp(processEntry.szExeFile, pName) == 0) {
            ret = processEntry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    } while(Process32Next(snapHandle, &processEntry)); //получаем следующий процесс

    /*закрываем указатель на объект в ядре*/
    CloseHandle(snapHandle);

    return ret;
}

/*включение/выключение нужной привелегии*/
BOOL setPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR szPrivName, BOOL isOn) {
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = {1}; // tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    if(!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, szPrivName, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid)) {
        show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось найти привелегию по имени"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = isOn ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED;

    if(!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL)) {
        show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось установить/снять привилегию"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    /*получаем указатель текущего процесса*/
    HANDLE hCurrentProc = GetCurrentProcess();

    /*получаем ключ доступа нашего процесса*/
    HANDLE hToken;
    if(!OpenProcessToken(hCurrentProc, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) {
        show_err(_TEXT("OpenProcessToken Error"));
        return 1;
    } else if(!setPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE)) /*добавляем нашему процессу привелегию отладки, чтоб писать в память другого процесса*/
        return 1;

    /*получаем идентификатор нужного процесса по его имени*/        
    DWORD pid = getProcessID(_TEXT("Skype.exe"));       
    if(pid == 0) {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Не удалось найти нужный процесс.\n"));
        return 1;
    }
    /*открываем другой процесс*/
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, /*флаг доступа*/
                               FALSE,              /*признак наследования получаемого дескриптора*/
                               pid);               /*идентификатор открываемого процесса*/

    if(hProc == NULL) {
        show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось открыть требуемый процесс"));
        return 1;
    }

    /*ПРОЧИТАЕМ НУЖНЫЕ НАМ ДАННЫЕ*/
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    /*буфер под считываемый регион*/
    PBYTE Buffer = malloc(65536);

    /*выбеляем память в адресном пространстве процесса*/
    LPVOID p = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 65536, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if(NULL == p)
        return show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось выделить память в виртуальном адресном пространстве процесса"));
    else
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Aдрес выделенного региона %x\n"), p);

    LPVOID lpMem = 0;   
    while(lpMem < si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress) {
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
        VirtualQueryEx(hProc, lpMem, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));   // Узнаем о текущем регионе памяти.

        if(mbi.Protect & PAGE_READWRITE 
           || mbi.Protect & PAGE_WRITECOPY
           || mbi.Protect & PAGE_READONLY) {

            /*считываю весь найденный регион*/
            DWORD dwRead = 0;
            if(!ReadProcessMemory(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, Buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &dwRead))
                return show_err(_TEXT("Не удалось прочитать регион памяти процесса"));

            _tprintf(_TEXT("Начальный адрес просматриваемого региона %x\n"), mbi.BaseAddress);


            ///*пишем в память процесса (так ради понта)*/
            if(mbi.Protect & PAGE_READWRITE
               || mbi.Protect & PAGE_WRITECOPY) {
                DWORD dwWritten = 0;
                if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProc, p, Buffer, dwRead, &dwWritten))
                    return show_err(_TEXT("Ошибка записи в регион данных памяти"));                     
            }
        }

        /*переход к следующему региону*/
        lpMem = (LPVOID)((DWORD)mbi.BaseAddress + (DWORD)mbi.RegionSize);

    }

    /*освобождаем память удаленного процесса*/
    VirtualFree(p, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    /*освобождаем память у себя*/
    free(Buffer);

    /*Закрываем все указатели*/ 
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hCurrentProc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Named pipe и сокетов хватит для 5000 сообщений в секунду?